# Make multiple API requests with different request body sequentially

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit2, rx-java2

The use case : I need to send some request in the server using android client (retrofit). After I get my first answer , i need to update the sending object values (that depend on the last item that I get) and resend it until all data are downloaded. I want to know how can I achieve this with Retrofit and RxJava (I don't want to use while loops etc)

EDIT : 
The thing is , I don't know the exact number of the "flat maps" because the data might get larger or smaller . I have lets say 420000 records and for every request I donwload 1000 data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could `flatMap` them, and using its response in the next one, by using the `it` parameter, which is the response of the previous.

```
mathApi.multiplyByTwo(1)
    .flatMap {
        mathApi.multiplyByTwo(it)
    }.flatMap {
        mathApi.multiplyByTwo(it)
    }.subscribe {
        // here "it" will be 4 (1*2*2) 
    }
```

And in case you don't know how many `flatMap`s you will end up having, you could, for instance, do it with a recursive function.

```
private fun multiplyByTwo(number: Int) {
    mathApi.multiplyByTwo(number).subscribe {
        if (it < Integer.MAX_VALUE) { // When you run out of data.
            multiplyByTwo(it)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also he could use coroutines. No while loops etc)

Comment: The thing is , I don't know the exact number of the "flat maps" because the data might get larger or smaller . I have lets say 420000 records and for every request I donwload 1000 data .

Comment: In this case, I'd simply write a recursive function. I'll edit my response.

Comment: Are you trying to obtain data from your API a page at a time?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the generate function that holds a mutable state:

```
data class ApiResponse(
    val nextPage: Int? = null
)

data class GeneratorState(
    var lastResponse: ApiResponse
)

fun makeApiCall(page: Int): ApiResponse {
    return ApiResponse(page + 1)
}

Flowable
    .generate(
        Callable { GeneratorState(makeApiCall(0)) },
        BiConsumer { state: GeneratorState, emitter: Emitter<ApiResponse> ->
            val latest = state.lastResponse

            if (latest.nextPage != null) {
                val response = makeApiCall(latest.nextPage)
                state.lastResponse = response
                emitter.onNext(response)
            } else {
                emitter.onComplete()
            }
        })
    .subscribe(object : FlowableSubscriber<ApiResponse> {
        var subscription: Subscription? = null

        override fun onSubscribe(s: Subscription) {
            subscription = s
            s.request(1)
        }

        override fun onNext(response: ApiResponse) {
            println("onNext :$response")
            if (response.nextPage != null && response.nextPage < 10) {
                subscription?.request(1)
            } else {
                subscription?.cancel()
            }
        }

        override fun onComplete() {
            println("Completed")
        }

        override fun onError(t: Throwable) {
            t.printStackTrace()
        }
    })
```